# HTML5/CSS3 iPad 3D

Tags: html, css, ipad, geometry

I would like to combine the iPads orientation sensors (I saw some javascript event handler based stuff, but don't remember where) and CSS3 3D transformation features to create a navigation 'paradigm' where the navigable content is projected onto the inner surface of a sphere and the navigating user (the iPad)  being in the center of that sphere.

I would be very grateful for hints pointing me into the right direction. Are there any high-level HTML5/CSS3 APIs/frameworks/libraries already?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/ Here are examples of device orientation.

Comment: Definitely a good start, thx a lot. Will dive into once time permits.

Comment: :) How do you think moving the device to interact with the content? Imagine turning it 90 degrees on the X axis, you could not see the screen hehe

Comment: you got it ;-) atm I'm thinking of QR codes - thus envolving the cam - on the wall 'resetting' position/orientation to a known state.

Comment: Ok, so were talking about an application, right? With html5 and javascript, phonegap could help you... Or online webapp and qr? mmm i dont know.

Comment: Basically yes - but I would be happy having a pointer to a framework which allows me to do such transformations - even before doing navigation.